# Faster way of searching for Top Level Windows in WPF CodedUI

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I have several parts of my application that are supposed to close a window.
Checking that these windows have been closed using Coded-UI is incredibly slow. Right now my code looks like this:

```
Assert.IsFalse(UIMap.SomeWindow.TryFind(),
            "X Window found when should be closed");
```

The problem is, this takes around 30s to search, and there are around 5 times this is used, and I have around 10 similar windows all being tested. I'd like to trim this time if possible, as it's making my tests slow.

I have also tried a dynamic solution (which is basically identical to the UIMap implementation):

```
var window = new WpfWindow();
window.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "Window Title");
Assert.IsFalse(window.TryFind());
```

This is just as slow. It would be nice to use ApplicationUnderTest as a search parent, but as the window is Top Level, it doesn't seem to work.

Surely it shouldn't be too hard just to look at the open windows on my system (5), and check their titles against the search parameter?

Edit: Using SearchConfiguration.VisibleOnly doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer, surprisingly on LinkedIn.

Now using:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 1000; //in ms
Playback.PlaybackSettings.ShouldSearchFailFast = true;
```

Source: https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/3828241-5843659258196959234

(C&P):

```
//Search Settings

// Value is in milliseconds. Default search timeout is 2 minutes. 
// The search engine will continue making passes until the timeout has expired 
// or the window has been found.
settings.SearchTimeout = 10000;

// Default search will make 3 attempts. 
// If true the default 3 attempts is applied. If false then only one attempt should take place. 
settings.ShouldSearchFailFast = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a better answer. If set a global configuration like that and have to deal with a WPF Table and find a specific cell you might not find it working.

Using Window name generally isn't a great idea if there is any dynamic titles, Control Name is a good constant. It sounds to me like you are passing bad SearchProperties. You can use DrawHighlight() to see if CUI is actually finding your controls.  First pass in the main parent window to your close window method, then use it as a try.

```
public static WinWindow _mainParent(string MainParentCtlName)
    {
        var _mainForm = new WinWindow();
        _mainForm.SearchProperties.Add("ControlName", MainParentCtlName);
        return _mainForm;
    }
public static void CloseWindow(string MainWinCtlName)
    {
        var close = new WinButton(_mainParent(MainWinCtlName));
        close.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Close");
        Mouse.Click(close);
    }
try
{CloseWindow("MainWindowForm")}
catch{}
```